# Time between keydown and key up

Tags: javascript, html, time

So I'm trying to find the time between then moment a user presses down on the T key and and when the key is released. I've looked everywhere, but I've yet to find a working solution. Various solutions return numbers, but not the right ones. Here's my javascript:

```
var ky;
var start;
var end;

function keydown(e){
    ky = e.keyCode;
    if(ky==84){
        start = +new Date();
    }
}

function keyup(e){
    ky = e.keyCode;
    if(ky==84){
        end = +new Date();
        alert(end - start);
    }
}
```

In the body tag I have onkeydown="keydown(event)" onkeyup="keyup(event)"

And instead of returning the milliseconds between the keydown and keyup and gives me a number between about 20 and 200. I can't really give you the whole code because It includes a lot of other code that is not part of it the keyup and keydown

Comment: So... are you handling the actual events anywhere?

Comment: but not the right ones.  <- how are you sure that they are wrong?

Comment: When you figure out how to handle the key ups and downs, remember that it is possible to hold down a key and press and release any number of other keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "not the right ones"? Bear in mind that the delta between two Date objects will be in milliseconds, are you just expecting a different unit?

Comment: I concur with @ChrisSubagio, JS dates are in milliseconds, so your values between 20 and 200 represent 1/50 and 1/5 of a second.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but auto-repeat may be messing up your timing if you hold the key down longer than the auto-repeat time (typically around 500ms).  You can work-around the auto-repeat with code like this:

```
var start = 0;
function processKeyDown(e) {
    if (!start) {
        start = (new Date()).getTime();
    }
}

function processKeyUp(e) {
    var delta = (new Date()).getTime() - start;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = delta + " ms";
    start = 0;
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/AveZP/

Comment: Note that this won't work under Opera 12 (and probably earlier) on GNU/Linux.